# set tab width for less output

Tags: less, tabulation

Is it possible for `less` output to set the tab width to a number `X` as it is for [cat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782861/3739455)?

Comment: You don't need to change the tabs length setting to output a file with reduced tab size. Just use `expand` instead of `cat`, like so: `expand -4 residuum.txt`.

Comment: I just thought I'd drop by to mention that while expand and unexpand are cool, there is also  the `tabs` command. Sadly `less` seems to ignore or reset what the terminal tabstops are set to. It's in posix: https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/tabs/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `less -x` or `less --tabs`, e.g. `less -x4` will set the tabwidth to 4.

You can configure defaults with the `LESS` environment variable, e.g. `LESS="-x4"`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Didn't find the option. I'll accept your answer as soon as it is possible :)!

Answer (score 36):

The `less`-specific answer [has already been given](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147444/22565), but a generic solution (for any pager) is to expand the `tabs` (with space characters) with the `expand` command before feeding to the pager:

```
expand -t4 file | pager
```

Comment: Ah ok :), good to know! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of setting the tab width in command line (before you open `less`). You can also set the tab width within `less` by typing `-x4`

Comment: This is the answer I really needed. Who *always* knows how wide they want tabs before they even open the file?